# Новый столбец таблицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Не могу решить простую проблему.
У меня есть большой сет данных (data), в нем более 40 столбцов и 25 тысяч строк.
В каждой ячейке столбца 'group' находится одно из трех значений: 'Первый'; 'Последний' или 'Другой'.
Необходимо создать новый столбец 'group_new', где каждому из этих трёх значений прямо бы соответствовали числа 1, 2 или 3.
Пытался создать конструкцию типа if-elif-else, но ничего не добился (возможно синтаксис путаю). Помогите справиться...
Вот что наваял.

```
if data['group'] == 'Первый':
    data['group_new'] == 1
elif data['group'] == 'Последний':
    data['group_new'] == 2
else:
    data['group_new'] == 3
```

Comment: это  pandas? приведите воспроизводимый кусок кода с тестовыми данными

Comment: Напоминаю, `==` - это оператор сравнения

Comment: Да! Это Pandas.
Про оператор сравнения помню, спасибо, как писал ранее, перепробовал много вариантов, это один из многих. Я не знаю как решить проблему, возможно там вообще другой подход нужен...

Comment: я же написал ответ, как это сделать

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': 77, 'b': 44 }
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1,2,3], 'c2': ['a', 'b', 'a']})
df.c2 = df.c2.replace(d)
print(df)
```

даст в результате

```
   c1  c2
0   1  77
1   2  44
2   3  77
```